# SQL Server: How to compare the results of two queries stored in variables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to compare two resultsets from queries that are stored in variables.

I've tried the following:

```
DECLARE @sql1 varchar(8000) = 'SELECT * FROM table1'
DECLARE @sql2 varchar(8000) = 'SELECT Col2, Col1 FROM table1'

IF EXISTS(
 (EXEC sp_executesql @sql1 
   EXCEPT 
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql2) 
    UNION ALL
 (EXEC sp_executesql @sql2
   EXCEPT 
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql1))
```

This approach has two problems: the if statement doesn't like `EXEC` statements (EXCEPT UNION ALL EXCEPT structure works when you use the actual queries instead of the variables).

The second problem is that, even if you use the actual queries, the order of the columns of both queries have to be the same or the resulsets will not match. For my purposes however, I need those resultsets to match. I think I need a way to order the columns but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

EDIT:
I have no control over the incoming queries because this is code for an application that's meant to check an answer query of a student against the teacher's query. I can't choose to not use *.

Comment: Try and look up the at EXCEPT operator. It might help you

Comment: Simply *don't* use `*` and *don't* depend on an arbitrary column order. Write a proper statement whose subqueries explicitly specify the columns they want to return

Comment: Can you assure that the queries from the variables return the same columns? are the column names identical?

Comment: @RaulSebastian Not really, since students can give wrong answers. The column names will most likely be identical though.

Comment: So just to make sure, you want the tuples from the result of sql1 that are also included in sql2 and vice versa?

Comment: @RaulSebastian The statement is meant to return true if rows exist after the EXCEPT-UNION ALL-EXCEPT structure. The idea is that if sql1 and sql2 give the same result, they cancel eachother out and the EXISTS will return 0.

Comment: This is never going to work as you are hoping. Consider if the datatypes of Col1 and Col2 are not the same. That will mean an implicit conversion and likely throw exceptions. You also can't mix dynamic sql and standard t-sql in the same command.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve is something that is not meant to be done in SQL Server. A rather clean way would be to have a code that executes each query and compares both resulting data sets, by metadata and value by value.

I do not recommend you to use the following approach.

For testing purposes I created this stored procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'SP_CompareQueryResults')
    DROP PROCEDURE SP_CompareQueryResults
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CompareQueryResults 
(
    @sql1 NVARCHAR(4000)
  , @sql2 NVARCHAR(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @q1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = @sql1
, @q2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = @sql2

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##q1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##q1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##q2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##q2

SET @q1 = 'SELECT * INTO ##q1 FROM (' + @q1 + ') r'
SET @q2 = 'SELECT * INTO ##q2 FROM (' + @q2 + ') r'

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC (@q1)
    EXEC (@q2)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'One of the source queries are not valid.'
    RETURN
END CATCH

DECLARE @r NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @r = COALESCE(@r + ', ', ' ') + COLUMN_NAME
FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##q1' 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##q2'
) r

SET @r = 'SELECT 1 as SourceQuery, * FROM (SELECT ' + @r + ' FROM ##q1 EXCEPT SELECT' + @r + ' FROM ##q2) r'
+ ' UNION ALL SELECT 2 as SourceQuery, * FROM (SELECT ' + @r + ' FROM ##q2 EXCEPT SELECT' + @r + ' FROM ##q1) r'

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(@r)    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'Queries have not matching metadata.'
    RETURN
END CATCH

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##q1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##q1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##q2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##q2
END
GO
```

It finds columns with the same names from both queries and compares each of the queries results, returning rows from query 1 not included in query 2 and the other way around.

Let's say you have two queries with following results:

[image: sql query one]

and another one:

[image: sql query two]

As you can see the second query has an additional column, columns are not in the same order and only one tuple is in both queries.

Executing the above SP like this:

```
EXEC SP_CompareQueryResults
@sql1 = N'
SELECT 1 AS ID
, ''test'' AS Value
, CAST(1 as BIT) AS Valid
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, ''test2'', 0',
@sql2 = N'
SELECT 1 AS ID
, CAST(1 as BIT) AS Valid
, ''test'' AS Value
, ''test'' AS AnotherValue
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 1, ''test2'', ''whatever'''
```

gives you the none matching tuples from both queries:

[image: results]

If both queries yield the same results, the SP_CompareQueryResults will not return any rows, so you could say they have same values for the columns with matching names. Same thing happens if both queries have no resulting rows, giving a false positive. You can tweak the above procedure for your needs.

DO NOT USE this code in a production environment as it can be SQL injected and I have not tested this. Generally avoid dynamic sql, if not necessary.

As first stated, try to write for example a c# code is sql injection safe and compares the results.